# Acegi Security Issue

Tags: spring-security

I have the following security config (i.e. http channel requirements) for my webapp:

```
<bean id="channelProcessingFilter" class="org.acegisecurity.securechannel.ChannelProcessingFilter">
    <property name="channelDecisionManager"><ref bean="channelDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="filterInvocationDefinitionSource">
        <value>
            ...
            \A/.*.html\Z=REQUIRES_INSECURE_CHANNEL
    </value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

where all *.html URLs require http access (insecure channel).  This explains why I’m seeing https requests switch to http.  When I change the config to require https access (secure channel), then I can’t get to the page via http.

My questions is: Does anyone know if it’s possible to allow either http or https access?

Comment: How about just NOT configuring a channelProcessingFilter? Or making sure no rule are applied to any URl ending in ".html"? The processingFilter will then ignore these URLs, and let the request be processed

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use a filter in this case because insecure channels are required in general.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there exists a setting called ANY_CHANNELS in some implementations.  Unfortunately, not mine.